# Non-rectangular back-ground images

Tags: css

I saw this PSD of a landing page at Pinterest and I was wondering how I could achieve the same style using css: having a non-rectangular image cutting the one above it. Is there any easy way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Hospital landing page]

Comment: you can start here 
https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: show us what you tried (html + css) and we might point you in the right direction :)

Comment: if possible - get a transparent background cropped image. that's simplest IMO